# Drawing at cursor position on canvas with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw, point, mouse-cursor

I am trying to draw over a canvas by clicking and dragging the mouse. My problem is that, apart from the fact that the line has a very poor quality (I want a more pronounced border) it only respects the mouse position when this is at 0,0. As I move the mouse to the lower corner, the line increments its distance from it as much as when I am in the middle of the canvas, the line is already out of it.
I have my code at: http://jsfiddle.net/ajTkP/12/

I will also post it here:

```
var MDown = false;
var Color = 'blue';

var Canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var Context = Canvas.getContext('2d');

Canvas.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
Canvas.unselectable = "on";
Canvas.style.MozUserSelect = "none";

Canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    MDown = true;
    Context.strokeStyle = Color;
    Context.lineWidth = 3;
    Context.lineCap = 'round';
    Context.beginPath();
    Context.moveTo(e.pageX - Position(Canvas).left, e.pageY - 5);
}

Canvas.onmouseup = function() { MDown = false; };

Canvas.onmousemove = function(e) { 
    if (MDown) {
        Context.lineTo(e.pageX - Position(Canvas).left, e.pageY - 5);
        Context.stroke();
    }
}

function Position(el) {
    var position = {left: 0, top: 0};
    if (el) {
        if (!isNaN(el.offsetLeft) && !isNaN(el.offsetTop)) {
            position.left += el.offsetLeft;
            position.top += el.offsetTop;
        }
    }
    return position;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set an explicit `width` and `height` on the canvas.  The default dimensions of a canvas are a width of 300 and a height of 150 ([see the spec here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html)).  By setting the width and height via CSS you are just stretching the canvas.

Either do:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

or set the width/height via JavaScript:

```
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 200;
```

See the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajTkP/13/

Comment: You saved a man's life. God bless you. Any tips to make the line smoother? Thanks again!

Comment: FYI, it is better to do this `window.onmousemove` so the line won't get stuck when you move out the area http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ajTkP/14/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jimr beat me to the punch about the canvas height and width.

The poor quality of the line though is due to how you're drawing the line. You'll notice that you're calling `stroke()` on **every** onmousemove event. Keep in mind that it's keeping track of the path of the line from when you `beginPath()` to when you `closePath()`, so you're basically stroking the same line multiple times (every time your mouse moves). This is what's giving you the aliased (blocky-looking) lines, instead of the smooth anti-aliased lines you're expecting.

Comment: So, should I call stroke when mouseup()? If I do that I cannot see the line till I mouseup().

Comment: I don't know if there's a better way of doing it, but you could try saving the previous position and do a `moveTo(previousPosition)`, `lineTo(currentPoisition)`, and `stroke()`. You might get a gap in between each line though so you might need to play around with it a bit.

Comment: Just looked through some canvas drawing app tutorials, and found [another method](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/) of doing it. It's basically redrawing the whole line (albeit a bit longer each time) every time the mouse moves. Since it's drawn so fast, the user doesn't notice that the line is being redrawn. Not very elegant, but it works.